# Does Wayland use XKB for keyboard layouts?

Tags: keyboard-layout, xkb, wayland

As XKB is part of X window, is it XKB used in Wayland as well? If so, is there any utility planed to replace XKB at some point?

In weston, setxkbmap does not work obviously. What is the currently recommended way to change keyboard layout?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Yes, Wayland uses XKB for keyboard layouts. But it's not quite the right question, because things work different than in X. Remember that Wayland is only a protocol (plus a wrapper library).

At the protocol level, wayland has a wl_keyboard.keymap event. This event contains a file descriptor to the keymap and a format classifier. Right now, only one format is defined: "xkb". So a wayland client will receive an XKB-compatible keymap and can use libxkbcommon to interpret that to get the right glyph on the screen, etc.

But Wayland does not define *how* this keymap is decided on. This decision is up to the compositor. In Weston, it is read from the config file on startup, in GNOME it comes from gsettings, etc. And this decision thus also defines how you can change keymaps at runtime (if at all possible). In GNOME you'd either use the config panel or you'd set the gsettings keys directly.

The X protocol has requests to set the keymap on the protocol level and these are what makes tools like setxkbmap possible. The Wayland does not have these requests, it's not possible to set the keymap using the Wayland protocol alone.

Comment: Hi, could you please post and example on how to map keys on Gnome, or some reference material, I'm trying to change my right alt to enter.

Comment: @alejandrodnm Did you try [xremap](https://github.com/k0kubun/xremap)?

Comment: @PabloA, I just needed right alt to be enter. I did it editing `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc` and adding `key <RALT> { [ Return ] };` as
the last instruction of `xkb_symbols "pc105"`. 

This was many years ago and I haven't try again (change keyboard and laptop/OS)

Answer (score 4):

- You use [xkb configuration files](https://github.com/xkbcommon/libxkbcommon/pull/108/commits/bc4a691cb9f45c3309c78c997e00212f0978d082) in `$XDG_HOME_CONFIG/xkb/`.
- You can [create/extend layouts and variants](https://who-t.blogspot.com/2020/08/user-specific-xkb-configuration-part-3.html) in `$XDG_HOME_CONFIG/xkb/symbols/`.
- Optionally, you can also supplement your configuration with `$XDG_HOME_CONFIG/xkb/rulesets/evdev` if you want individual aspects of your configuration in `symbols` to be available as `xkb_options`.
- Also, if you want the options to show up in a GUI layout manager like GNOME tweaks, you need to [create `$XDG_HOME_CONFIG/xkb/rulesets/evdev.xml`](https://who-t.blogspot.com/2020/07/user-specific-xkb-configuration-part-2.html).

### More Resources

- [Full documentation on xkb configuration files](https://www.charvolant.org/doug/xkb/html/node5.html#SECTION00054000000000000000)
- [Additional resource on how to setup ~/.config/xkb](https://who-t.blogspot.com/2020/02/user-specific-xkb-configuration-part-1.html)
- [My own config](https://github.com/jnzigg/dotfiles/tree/master/.config/xkb)

Comment: Insane, thanks for your custom config. It looks awesome.