# Keyboard Layout with Sway on Fedora (Wayland)

Tags: fedora, keyboard-layout, wayland, sway

I have recently installed Fedora 27 which I find quite nice, I like the Gnome Desktop, but for working I definitely prefer a tiling window manager. I would like to use Sway because I was using i3 before and now that Gnome uses wayland I would like to make the change.

I have a french azerty keyboard which is well configured in Gnome, but Sway uses an U.S. layout. I don't know how I can make the change permanently, I can make a script for changing layout each time Sway run but I find this an ugly solution... Is there any proper way to do it so Sway can use the proper keyboard layout?

Thank you

PS: I read [that post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/309580/does-wayland-use-xkb-for-keyboard-layouts) but it did not help me, probably because I do not have enough knowledge regarding X.

Answer (score 9):

In newer versions of sway you can simple put the following lines in your config file:

```bsh
input * xkb_layout "de" # German keyboard layout
input * xkb_options "caps:escape" # Make Caps Lock an additional Esc
```

See [`xkeyboard-config(7)`](https://jlk.fjfi.cvut.cz/arch/manpages/man/xkeyboard-config.7) for a list of available layouts and options and [Sway#Keymap](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Sway#Keymap) on the ArchWiki.

Answer (score 5):

In the current release, `sway` only loads XKB layouts from environment variables at execution time (`XKB_DEFAULT_LAYOUT`, `XKB_DEFAULT_VARIANT`, `XKB_DEFAULT_OPTIONS`).  Wayland does not provide a server like X, so each Wayland compositor has to implement its own method for setting or changing layouts -- generic tools like `setxkbmap` are out unless/until a protocol is defined/adopted that will allow the tool to talk to any compositor.

Eventually, `sway` will add the ability to change layouts during runtime.  [This pull request](https://github.com/swaywm/sway/pull/1505) adds `swaymsg input` subcommands to set XKB options at runtime; it's presently in the development branch (`wlroots`).  If it is released as in that PR, you'd be able to issue commands like these to change the keyboard:

```
swaymsg input 0:0:X11_keyboard xkb_layout de
```

Comment: So that means I will not be able to use Sway properly for now? Wayland is cool but it adds a lot of works to be done by the WM.

Answer (score 0):

To change the keyboard layout, you need to set some environment variables before launching Sway. While we wait for Sway 1.0 this is the correct way of doing it.

- `cp /usr/share/wayland-sessions/sway.desktop /usr/share/wayland-sessions/sway-custom.desktop`
- Open `sway-custom.desktop` and enter

  - `[Desktop Entry]
    Name=SwayCustom
    Comment=SirCmpwn's Wayland window manager
    Exec=sway-custom
    Type=Application`
- Create `/bin/sway-custom` and enter

  - `#!/bin/bash
    export XKB_DEFAULT_OPTIONS=caps:escape # enter your options here
    sway`
- `chmod +x /bin/sway-custom`
- Restart your computer and choose `SwayCustom` from the list of window managers before logging in