# prevent xkb layout from changing

Tags: linux-mint, keyboard-layout, xkb

I have a customized layout, but it keeps (what seems to be randomly) changing to default, I am not sure what I need to do more:

```
// cat .profile
setxkbmap -layout fr2

denis:~ $ uname -r
4.15.0-62-generic

denis:~ $ cat /etc/os-release 
NAME="Linux Mint"
VERSION="18.3 (Sylvia)"
ID=linuxmint
ID_LIKE=ubuntu
PRETTY_NAME="Linux Mint 18.3"
VERSION_ID="18.3"
HOME_URL="http://www.linuxmint.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://forums.linuxmint.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/linuxmint/"
VERSION_CODENAME=sylvia
UBUNTU_CODENAME=xenial
```

Comment: A layout of what: Windows, icons, cuddly toys?

Comment: what? `xkb` is about keyboard

Comment: @mosvy thinks for the edit, it makes sense now, that you have put xkb in the title.

Answer (score 0):

[Several distros are having this problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/451945/permanently-set-keyboard-layout-options-with-setxkbmap-in-gnome-unity). Create a `.desktop` file with the `setxkbmap` code and put it in `~/.config/autostart/`. To keep the configuration, use this command.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.keyboard active false
```

If the command won't work, others have reported using something other than ibus or disable any screen locking that might reload the default layout.

Comment: thank you, i ll try this out

Comment: Ok well, for future reference, this is not enough

Comment: It depends on the compositor you're using. Or go back to using X instead of Wayland, which can't handle keymaps. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/309580/does-wayland-use-xkb-for-keyboard-layouts

Comment: I am not under Wayland, and never was..

Comment: Changed from Cinnamon to MATE, which doesnt have this problem. Not a fix, but works for me lol