Layout `custom` not recognised by KDE keyboard layout settings
I want to get started with a new keyboard layout from the Neo family. It is Noted, and I tried to install it according to this guide. In a nutshell, I downloaded a file called custom and put it to the symbols folder:
curl 'https://dl.neo-layout.org/custom_noted' | sudo tee /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/custom
After that I should be able to select a custom layout from the keyboard layout settings. Unfortunately, custom does not show up. It also does not show up for a fresh test user on the same installation. However, I can use it via setxkbmap.
If I set up a fresh Debian Testing in a virtual environment, the above step works. I also checked the contents of /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/* and all files are the same in the VM and on my Debian.
I use Debian Testing with KDE, which I upgraded from Debian Bookworm. It could be that the Bookworm was Bullseye before, since the installation is very old. Reinstallation from scratch is not an option here. The issue is reproducible on two similar configured Debian machines of mine. It also does not matter whether I chose X11 or Wayland.
I really need some help investigating this. What could I change to get the custom layout show up?

Try step 2 in my answer in the link, this worked for me back when I used the Cinnamon desktop environment. Essentially you need to add an entry for that menu to find. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/707507/permanently-remap-caps-lock-to-escape/709459#709459

This depends on the localisations.
In KDE (and Xfce4 and presumably some other DEs as well) the short tag is not shown in the dialog. Only the description text is. This text reads A user defined custom layout in English. Since this text contains custom, it is presented when looking for that.
Once the system language is set to something else, e.g. German, the localised description is shown. It reads Eine benutzerdefinierte Belegung in German and is not shown when looking for custom.
Thus, the option was always there but has to be selected by its localised description.
